# File sometimes being deleted before download is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have a page where a user clicks on a button to download a file. It is supposed to decrypt the file, download the file, and then delete the decrypted file. What is intermittently happening is that the deletion is happening before the download is complete. Sometimes the file is partially downloaded, sometimes not at all.

I would normally download the files server side, but since this is an AJAX page the method I use for that does not appear to work. So instead I am doing some back and forth from server and client side.

Here is the VB.NET server side sub fired after button click:

```vb
Sub DownloadFile()
    output = MapPath + _hdnFilePath.Value
    input = output.Replace("_dec", "_enc")
    crptFile.Decrypt(input, output)
    Dim encodedFileName As String = _hdnFilePath.Value.Replace("'", "@@@")
    RadAjaxManager1.ResponseScripts.Add("downloadURI('" & encodedFileName & "');")
    ''OLD  DOWNLOAD METHOD BELOW - does not work with ajax
    'Response.Clear()
    'Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    'Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + 
    'Path.GetFileName(output))
    'Response.WriteFile(output)
    'Response.Flush()

    'Delete the decrypted (output) file.
    'File.Delete(output)
End Sub
```

Here is the javascript fired by this function:

```js
function downloadURI(encodedFileName) {
    encodedFileName = encodedFileName.replace(/\@\@\@/g, "'");
    var encodedURI = encodeURIComponent(encodedFileName)
    encodedFileName = encodedFileName.replace("###", "%").replace("$$$", "&")
    fetch('<%= ResolveUrl("/CUTracking/CUFiles/") %>' + encodedURI)
        .then(resp => resp.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.style.display = 'none';
            a.href = url;
            a.download = encodedFileName;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            a.remove();
        })
        .catch(() => alert('There was an error'));
    $find("<%= RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("Delete")
}
```

And here is the delete VB.NET sub fired by the javascript download function:

```vb
Protected Sub RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest(sender As Object, e As 
    AjaxRequestEventArgs)
    If e.Argument = "Delete" Then
        File.Delete(MapPath + _hdnFilePath.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there any way I can prevent the file from getting deleted too early, or is there a less roundabout way of going about this? I am only using a blob in an attempt to fix this issue, and only using javascript for downloading the file because my server side method is not working with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion won't solve the sync problem you're facing, but there's room for improvement in your downloading script.

When you create a temporary element (an anchor in this case) there’s no need to append it to the document...

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

const a = document.createElement('a');

a.style.display = 'none';   // <-- You don't need this

a.href = url;

a.download = encodedFileName;

document.body.appendChild(a);  // <-- You don't need this

a.click();

window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

a.remove();  // <-- You don't need this
```

Also, downloads should open in a new window resulting in this improved version...

```
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var a = document.createElement('a');

a.target = '_blank'; // <-- new window

a.href = url;

a.download = encodedFileName;

a.click();

window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

The other thing I’ve changed was to change your const declarations to vars.

A constant should be used for data that will never change such as the days of the week or months of the year, like this:

```
const DaysOfWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
```

Take note that you are wisely revoking (deleting/editing) the blob, so it should be a var.

Constant declarations tell the O/S to reserve the exact size in memory for that declaration throughout the duration of the program running because the data will never change, but you want that blob to be gone and for the memory occupied to be freed up right?